# PHP: preg_match for "some multiple words string" + [\s* + "<some.email@address>"]

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Need for parse strings which are appears in the following possible forms:

```
Some User Name 
Some User Name <user.mail@address>
```

So username (multiple words) always exists but email is optional and contained in angle brackets.

I need to catch from those:

1. Username, one string with multiple words separated by \s or \h
2. Following next email address (if exists) without angle brackets. If no email address specified then resulting submask array should be empty (but always exists in result).

I tried some variations of

`preg_match('/^(.*?)\s*(?:\<(.*)\>)?$/s', $in, $out)`

but this not work.

Thanks anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the separate words separated by `\h` and an optional email address, you could make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches, asserting the position at the end of the previous match.

```
(?|^(\w+)|\G(?!^)\h+(\w+))(?:\h+<([^<>\r\n]+)>$)?
```

*Explanation*

- `(?|` [Branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (To keep the words in `$matches[1]`)

  - `^(\w+)` Start of string, match 1+ word chars in **group 1**
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
  - `\h+(\w+)` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars in **group 1**
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `<([^<>\r\n]+)>$` Capture the email address between `<>` in **group 2** at the end of string
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1KivG/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Z1Bmm)

---

Use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all the values.

The default flag is `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` which:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
>   matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

The words are in `$matches[1]` and the email is in `$matches2`

If the email is not present, the array will be there, but empty.

You could use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty entries from the email array.

```
Example code

$pattern = "~(?|^(\w+)|\G(?!^)\h+(\w+))(?:\h+<([^<>\r\n]+)>$)?~";
$strings = [
    "Some User Name ",
    "Some User Name <user.mail@address>"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
    print_r(array_filter($matches[2]));
}
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some
    [1] => User
    [2] => Name
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some
    [1] => User
    [2] => Name
)
Array
(
    [2] => user.mail@address
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like this is what I looked for.

Comment: UPD. One detail which I forgot. Username (if this possible) is better as the single string (with multiple words) for my purpose. I fixed that above.

Comment: @CodeSmith Do you want `Some` and `UserName` as separate words? What is the logic to get the User Name? Is it always the second and the third word?  Is is always 2 words? What if it is `Some Test User Name` or just `User Name` or `Some Test User Name Here`?

Comment: Sorry if I've been not clear. Username means the entire string  (`"Some User Name"` or `"Some Test User Name Here"`) before `<user.mail@address>` (if present one) or before end-of-string (if no email address specified). I just want to accent that it may contains multiple space-separated words so it is not single-word username.

But anyway I already use your solution via `join('', $matches[1])` to concatenate username words. Thank you very match again.